# Nested CALCULATE() expressions to sum for related projects where criteria met

Tags: dax

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958177/powerpivot-hierarchy-detection-active-projects/32958788?noredirect=1#comment53747587_32958788) I'm looking to calculate ratios of expenses/payments for matter groups in a denormalised hierarchy. The time aspect is tricky, I want to see fact summaries for all time, but only for matters where the last matter closed in the current Financial Year (ending 30 June). Each project has indicators of whether it is the last closed in its parent matter group, and a closure date.

A first step in this would be to calculate the total received across all matters which have a matter closed in the current financial YTD. This psuedocode would be something like:

- Filter to only show matters which were closed in current FY && were the last closed in their group
- Remove filters, and sum fact table (payments in this example) for all matters with the same [UniqueParentName]
- Add all those sums together.

This sounded like a prime opportunity for SUMX(), but the layering of CALCULATE() and the filter management is getting me turned around. I've used trial code as follows:

```
Recovered on closed this FY :=CALCULATE (
CALCULATE (
    [Recovery All Time],
    ALLEXCEPT (
        MatterListView,
        MatterListView[UniqueParentName]
    )
),
MatterListView[LastClosed] = TRUE (),
USERELATIONSHIP ( MatterListView[ClosureDate], Date_Table[dateDate] ),
DATESYTD ( Date_Table[dateDate], "30 June" ))
```

This relying on [Recovery All Time], which is currently a simple:

```
=CALCULATE (
SUM ( MatterPayment[Payment Amount] ),
ALL ( Date_Table[DateDate] ))
```

Comment: Your data model is inscrutable from your post. Can you share sample data or a model diagram with us, with an explanation of relationships relevant to the measures in question? Additionally, is there a need to do this reporting for arbitrary fiscal years into the past, or just for the actual current fiscal year according today's date?

Answer (score 0):

No idea but filters/calculates is where I always misunderstand what it is doing.

Disclaimer, I am still learning DAX myself but have you tried to use a FILTER() instead of a nested CALCULATE()? Matter of fact, do you need the second calculate? (This is assuming that the trial code above is not working, apologies if this was not your question).

```
Recovered on closed this FY :=
CALCULATE (
    [Recovery All Time],
    ALLEXCEPT (
        MatterListView,
        MatterListView[UniqueParentName]
    ),
    MatterListView[LastClosed] = TRUE (),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( MatterListView[ClosureDate], Date_Table[dateDate] ),
    DATESYTD ( Date_Table[dateDate], "30 June" )
)
```

From what I know, Measures get wrapped in a calculate so that is effectively three calculates which is probably the reason the results seem so illogical.

(Rep not high enough otherwise I would have made a comment)